# Java JPA EM.createNativeQuery(sql, someClass).getResultList()

Tags: java, jpa

How do I return a list of foobar as below?

```
@MappedSuperclass    
public abstract class foobar{}

@Entity
@Table(name="foobar")
public class foo extends foobar{}

@Entity
@Table(name="foobar")
public class bar extends foobar{}

List<foobar> results = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM foobar").getResultList();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to foobar.

Comment: Have you tried, `List<foobar> results = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM fobobar f").getResultList();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQL query of the form "`SELECT * FROM tbl`" will return each row as Object[]. Hence you should do

```
List<Object[]> results = ...
```

To map to a specific result class (whatever your foobar is), follow [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/native_query.html#SQL_Result_Definition). You can of course just use JPQL if wanting to map to entities.

Comment: Question about how to return list of foobar not list of object array.

Comment: question is about two things actually ... why it gives that error, answered, and how to get a specific result, now also answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<foobar> results = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM foobar", foobar.class).getResultList();
```

You must specify the class of the result to be cast.